# Hanging during matplotlib impor

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have problem with importing this part of code :

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg,NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
```

I am using matplotlib 1.5.3 and python version 3.5.2

I am doing application,when I need to show graph from matplotlib in tkinter

Comment: Of course it will hang as `matplotlib` is pretty huge and it takes time to load it.

Comment: @ForceBru: that comment makes no sense. Just because it's large doesn't mean it should hang on import.